# How to fix laravel middleware

Tags: laravel

Laravel middle-ware keeps redirecting me to welcome page even if the user is an admin. what i want is if a user is an admin,then he/she can view the routes for the admin, otherwise the user should be redirected to the root page "('/').
I believe i have done everything correctly but somehow i can not view the admin pages, i am redirected to the root page even if a user is an admin.
please assist me fix this bug.

**Admin middle-ware class**

```
class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
        return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id','photo_id','gender'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //A role Belongs to a User//
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }

    public function isAdmin(){
        if($this->role->name =='Administrator'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Routes(web.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/



Auth::routes();



Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'],function(){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/', [
        'uses'=>'HomeController@index',
        'as'=>'welcome'
        ]);

});

Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']],function(){
    Route::resource('/admin/users','AdminUsersController');

    Route::get('admin',[
        'uses'=>'AdminUsersController@dashboard',
        'as'=>'admin.index'
    ]);

    Route::get('admin/users',[
        'uses'=>'AdminUsersController@index',
        'as'=>'admin.users'
    ]);

    Route::get('admin/users/edit/{id}',[
        'as'=>'admin.users.edit',
        'uses'=>'AdminUsersController@edit'
    ]);

    Route::get('admin/users/create',[
        'as'=>'admin.users.create',
        'uses'=>'AdminUsersController@create'
    ]);
});
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Code seem fine, user is clearly not an administrator

Comment: Your admin middleware needs to run after the web middleware because the web middleware is responsible for booting up the session. 
Change your middlewares to:
['middleware'=>['web', 'admin']]

Comment: Thanks I have fixed it .i debugged user,role relationship with php tinker and it seems i mistyped "Administrator" to "Administrator/r/n"